# Como plotar/mapear os efeitos aleatórios espaciais (Spatial Random Effects) no R?

Tags: modelagem, r

Estou trabalhando com dados de leishmaniose visceral em setores censitários de um município brasileiro. Eu rodei um modelo espacial Baysiano (CAR conditional autoregressivel model) BYM do pacote CARBayes no software R. Entretanto, não estou conseguindo visualizar e exportar os efeitos aleatórios espaciais (Spatial Random Effects). Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso? Muito obgda.

```
modelbym1 <- S.CARbym(formula = eq1, data = spat.data,   
                family = "poisson", W = W2, burnin = 100000,  
                n.sample = 300000, thin = 20)
```

Comment: oi Patricia, não é possivel replicar seu erro com somente essa linha de codigo. Primeiro você poderia indicar seus pacotes com library(x) e em seguida gerar uma base de dados (ou usar uma das que ja existem no R, tipo iris, mtcars, etc), assim fica possivel poder te ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

O código para exportar os efeitos aleatórios espaciais é:

```
pmean = apply(modelbym1$samples$psi,2,mean) 
write.csv(pmean, file = "pmean.csv")
```

Então é só fazer um join com o ".shp" pq os valores são exportados na mesma ordem que os dados originais.